# Is there any possibility at all, that anything, bacteria, viruses, etc, can survive the plastic recycling process used for food and drink plastics?

Tags: bacteriology

**The Question**
-    Is there any possibility at all, that anything, bacteria, viruses, etc, can survive the plastic recycling process used for food and drink plastics ?

---

- Since I notice that some bacteria ? viruses ? survive on undersea volcanic vents, or other extremely hot places on earth.
- I am not wanting to put that industry on any disrepute. I wonder if bioplastics ( made from plants ) could be used for food and drink plastics or even for computers.
- I did some research into this topic, and definitely could not answer it.
- I assume that even if anything could survive the plastic recycling process, it would not be anything that could transfer and reside in the human body .
- I have put the second part of my question, into another question  [An experiment to confirm if anything can survive the plastic recycling process, and, if it could transfer itself into the food/drink, or human body?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/106715/an-experiment-to-confirm-if-anything-can-survive-the-plastic-recycling-process)

Comment: Could you show us the results of your prior investigations as per the [help], which you may remember being reminded the previous occasion that you asked this question. Also focus it a bit, the part about bioplastic computers seems to be a different topic.

Comment: I was thinking of removing that part about bioplastics and computers, however, it helps to show alternative plastics when looking at this subject from a greater distance

Comment: I have now added a second part to the question, asking what would be an experiment to confirm if this is possible - If anyone can indicate if or not that should be posted as a separate question ?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] from the [help]. You need to limit yourself to one question per question - this post has at least three. Also, "*I did some research into this topic, and definitely could not answer it*" is not acceptable as a prior research attempt. *Tell us* what you looked for, what you did learn, and where exactly you are stuck and need help.

Answer (score -1):

Prions can survive higher temperatures than those required to melt plastics. They cannot be sterilized or cooked away (the temperatures and times required aren't really cooking anymore).

https://dwr.virginia.gov/wildlife/diseases/cwd/what-are-prions/

https://deq.nd.gov/publications/AQ/documents/Chronic_Wasting_Disease_Burn.pdf

Comment: That's a good answer, I have no qualifications in this area so I didn't know about that one. I wonder if there are any types of spores ( en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spore ) that can survive these temperatures

Comment: Please add references to support your claims.

Comment: @MattDMo Isn't this common knowledge? Fine I'll get you references.